# How to get data from a MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm trying to get data from a `MutableLiveData`; however, it seems like something is wrong with the code, can you guys check for me please?
I can get the object, but I failed to add the object to a mutableList

```
properties = ArrayList()
    propertyViewModel.propertyItemLiveData.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer { propertyItems ->

            for (property in propertyItems){
                var p:Property = Property(property.id,property.address
                ,property.price,property.phone,property.lat,property.lon)
                println(p)// i can display data

                properties.add(p)//when i add to properties, the properties still null. Why?
            }
        }
    )
    if (properties.isEmpty()){
        println("null")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the observer will only run when `propertyItemLiveData` pushes a new value, or if it already has a value when you first `observe` it. But from [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects):

> **As soon as an app component is in the `STARTED` state, it receives the most recent value from the `LiveData` objects it’s observing**. This only occurs if the `LiveData` object to be observed has been set.

So you won't actually get a value until your `Activity` or `Fragment` hits the `onStart()` callback, meaning your observer code won't run until then. If the code you posted is running earlier than that (say in `onCreate`), then what you're doing is:

- creating an empty list
- adding an observer that will add stuff to that list (but it won't run until later)
- checking if the list is still empty (it definitely is)

Because of the observer pattern, where your code *reacts* to new data/events being *pushed* to it, whatever you need to do with that populated list should be part of the observer code. It should react to the new value and take action - update a list view, alert the user, start an API call, whatever

```
propertyViewModel.propertyItemLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { propertyItems ->
    // handle the propertyItems, add them to your list etc

    // then do whatever needs to happen with the list, e.g. display it
    updateDisplay(propertyList)
}
```

btw if `Property` is a `data class` and you're just copying all its data, you can add to your list like this:

```
properties.addAll(propertyItems.map { it.copy() })
// or propertyItems.map(Property::copy)
```

Answer (score 0):

hello first of all in kotlin in general you have to use mutableList and the check of empty or any other instruction should inside the call back like this :

```
properties =  mutableListOf<YourClass>()
    propertyViewModel.propertyItemLiveData.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        Observer { propertyItems ->

            for (property in propertyItems){
                var p:Property = Property(property.id,property.address
                ,property.price,property.phone,property.lat,property.lon)
                println(p)// i can display data

                properties.add(p)//when i add to properties, the properties 
            }

 if (properties.isEmpty()){
        println("null")
    }
        }
    )
```